# Remove all occurrences of a number from an array in place

Tags: javascript

I am working to solve the below problem,

> Given an array and a value, remove all instances of that value in
>   place and return the new length.

I have written the below code for it but it always return an empty array.

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {number}
 */
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (var i=0; i< nums.length; i++)
    {
            if (nums[i] == val)
                nums.slice(i);
    }
    return nums;
};
```

Comment: can you show how you run it

Comment: Your code doesn’t modify the array (`slice` returns a new array), so if you’re getting an empty array back it’s because you’re passing an empty array in. Anyway, look at [`splice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) and consider what happens to the next element when you splice something out.

Comment: `@return {number}` - no, you return nums, which is an array

Comment: Hint: When removing array items with `array.splice`, loop backwards not forwards. Alternatively, use `array.filter`. It's essentially what you're doing.

Comment: Consider using [*reduceRight*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight). Since you're modifying the array, you may skip indexes if looping from left to right.

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer Or just do `i--;` after doing the `splice`, which is my preferred method... less confusing imo :)

Comment: @Clonkex: Nice simple idea. I tried it but it gives an error of memory limit exceeding.

Comment: @FahadUddin Sorry? What idea? Doing `i--;`? That was in reply to @JosephtheDreamer. You should use @JaromandaX's answer.

Comment: @Clonkex - I actually prefer your answer, I've always hated going backwards through an array

Answer (score 6):

Use array SPLICE not slice

```js
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (var i=nums.length - 1; i >=0; i--) {
        if (nums[i] == val) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
        }
    }
    return nums.length;
};
var n = [1,2,3,2,1,2,3,2,1];
console.log(removeElement(n , 1));
console.log(n);
```

Also, note the function returns `nums.length` - as the requirement you stated is that the function returns the new length of the array

Comment: Sure, but using `splice` is like killing a fly with a sledgehammer.

Comment: @torazaburo - And that's...bad?

Comment: @JaromandaX Ok you know what, you and `nnnnnn` are right. I am _potentially_ misinterpreting the requirement based on the OP's flawed attempt to fulfill that requirement. I didn't notice that the comment-docs specified a number as return value. I was also assuming that returning the correct value was so blatantly obvious that the OP must have been returning the correct type. My mistake was compounded by the fact that the OP has a lot of rep, so I assumed he knew somewhat what he was doing, but the 44 "famous question" badges suggests he may have gotten the rep from questions, not answers.

Answer (score 5):

As others have pointed out, using `slice` won't accomplish anything at all. However, using `splice` instead, as many answers suggest, is both inefficient and unnecessary, and gives rise to awkwardness like needing to iterate through the array backward or adjust the loop index.

Instead, you can simply iterate through the array, copying the elements you want to keep right on top of the original elements, using a variable `j` to keep track of how many items we've kept so far. Then we adjust the length of the array (and return it, since that's the spec):

```
// Filter an array in place, removing elements equal to some value.
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (var i=0, j=0; i< nums.length; i++) {
      if (nums[i] !== val) nums[j++] = nums[i];
    }
    return nums.length = j;
};
```

However, this code is hard-wired only to filter on the specific condition that an element not be equal to some particular value. It would be more useful to write a general "filter-in-place" function:

```
// Filter an array in place, based on a condition.
function filterInPlace(arr, condition) {
  let j = 0;

  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
    if (condition(arr[i], i, arr)) arr[j++] = arr[i];

  return arr.length = j;
}
```

Now we can solve the original problem as follows:

```
// Remove a particular value from an array, in-place.
function removeElement(nums, val) {
  return filterInPlace(nums, function(value) { return value !== val; });
}
```

Here we've designed `condition` to take the same `(val, index, array)` signature as the function passed to `Array#filter`, just in case, even though the last two parameters are not used here.

Comment: This is a nice alternative. Might be nicer if the generic `filterInPlace()` function behaved like `.filter()` in passing `(element, index, array)` to the `condition` function - obviously not needed for the OP's problem, but if you're going to go generic...

Comment: I like this idea, but this `const notEqualTo = value => elt => elt !== value;` is ridiculously confusing, and why I strongly dislike the arrow-function syntax. +1 for offering the solution integrated into the OP's function AND the more generic ES6 alternative.

Comment: nice - I totally forgot assigning a value to array.length actually drops off elements from the array

Answer (score 2):

First, `slice()` doesn't remove items in an array, so start by changing that to `splice()`. Second, you need to decrease `i` when you remove an element so you don't skip any.

```js
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (var i=0; i< nums.length; i++)
    {
            if (nums[i] == val) {
                nums.splice(i,1);
                i--;
            }
    }
    return nums.length;
};

var nums = [5,2,3,6,1,2,4,2,5,6,1,3,6,2,4];
console.log(removeElement(nums,2));
console.log(nums);
```

Comment: @JaromandaX You were right, I did have the wrong arguments for `splice`, I forgot how it worked apparently. Thanks for pointing that out. However I do expect an array. That's what the OP is expecting too.

Comment: From the question: "and return the new length".

Comment: @JaromandaX I have edited my question. It's now basically the same as yours, but since I posted before you I feel ok in leaving it here. I'd appreciate it if you could remove the downvote, but you don't have to upvote.

Comment: @Clonkex - now that you are returning the correct thing, I prefer your answer :p

Comment: @JaromandaX Haha well thanks, I do apologise for being so stubborn, I was just frustrated that I answered _slightly_ first and then your answer got upvoted. My fault really, my answer wasn't even correct without many edits.

Comment: I come to SO to learn, I stay for the upvotes :p

Comment: Hopefully the OP won't now come along and say that you were right all along (despite what was in the question). Anyway, now that the answer reflects my understanding of the requirement I've happily voted it up. One last nitpick: even without `i--` I don't think the loop could "run over the end of the array", because the loop condition checks the current `.length`.

Comment: Yeah haha. Oh true, it would only skip checking an element each time it removed one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *reduceRight* to iterate over the array and remove elements that match the value to remove. You can determine whether `==` or `===` should be used for the comparison.

*reduceRight* is handy as it goes from right to left, so removing elements doesn't affect the index of the next element to inspect.

```js
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums - array of numbers to filter
 * @param {number} val    - value to remove from nums
 * @return {number} length of reduced array
 */
function removeElement(nums, val) {
  return nums.length? nums.reduceRight(function(acc, value, i) {
    if (value == val) nums.splice(i, 1);
    return nums
  }, null).length : 0;
};

var nums = [1,2,3,4,5,6,4];
var val  = 4;
console.log('Initial nums: ' + nums);
console.log('Value to remove: ' + val);
console.log('New length  : ' + removeElement(nums, val));
console.log('Final nums  : ' + nums);
```

Comment: I fail to see how `reduce` is doing anything useful here other than looping over the array backwards.

Comment: I don't understand this answer but it works, so +1

Comment: not so, @torazaburo, without it, the final result of reduce is undefined ... which has no length property - personally I'd move `.length` to `return nums.length`

Comment: @torazaburo—exactly. ;-) But that's like saying "*forEach does nothing useful as it just iterates over an array forwards*". I wouldn't have to use *reduceRight* if there was a *forEach* equivalent, maybe *forEachReverse*? ;-)

Comment: @Clonkex— *reduceRight* iterates backwards over the array so splicing elements doesn't affect them being visited. In a forwards loop, splicing the *i*th element means the `i+1` element is skipped (as it moves to *i* due to the splice) unless you adjust *i* each time you splice.

Comment: I understand iterating over elements that you're going to delete (in my answer I just did `i--` after the splice, because I greatly prefer the simplicity and ease of understanding of that method over iterating backwards), however I didn't know how `reduce` worked. With some googling I struggled through to success and it makes much more sense now. The unused `acc` parameter confused me too. I've always found the idea of having functions to run functions on each element of an array over-complicated. They're probably useful but I've not needed them so I don't know why they might be useful.

Comment: Well ok, the example given on the [Mozilla reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/ReduceRight) actually does a good job of demonstrating where they're useful. Idk how anyone manages to use them though, I feel like I'm learning to program all over again when I try to wrap my head around functions like that.

Comment: Wait, so the second parameter of `reduceRight` is optional, is there any reason you made it `null`?

Comment: @Clonkex—if no second parameter is provided, *reduceRight* uses the first value in the array as the accumulator. If there is only one element, it just returns the array and if there are no members, it throws an error. Providing *null* as an accumulator and testing for an empty array avoids those cases.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147764/discussion-between-clonkex-and-robg).

Answer (score 0):

Use filter :

```
var words = ["spray", "spray", "spray", "spray", "destruction", "present"];

var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
 return words.filter(function(word){
      return word !== val;
    }).length;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Within the function, find the first position within the `nums` array that matches `val`. If no match is found, the index is -1 and the function returns the length of the `nums` array. On the other hand, if there is a match, that item is removed and the function is called again recursively until there are no longer any matches.

```
/**
 * @param {number[]} nums
 * @param {number} val
 * @return {number}
 */
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
  const position = nums.findIndex(number => number === val);

  if(position === -1) {
    return nums.length;
  } else {
    nums.splice(position, 1);
  }

  return removeElement(nums, val);
};
```

Comment: Is `nums.findIndex(number => number === val)` different or better than `nums.indexOf(val)`?

Comment: I vote better, because it breaks IE into a million pieces :p

Answer (score -1):

Use splice method like:

```
nums.splice(i,1);
```

Hence, the code will look like this:

```js
var removeElement = function(nums, val) {
    for (var i=0; i <nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == val) {
            nums.splice(i,1);
            i--;
        }
    }
    return nums;
};
var arr = [5,3,7,8,5,5,2,5,55,4];
arr = removeElement(arr , 5);
console.log(arr);
console.log(arr.length);
```

It will remove only the particular element instead of sequence from ith position to the end

Comment: no, this is identical code to the question

Comment: @JayPatel try wrapping this in a snippet so we can see your code in action!

Comment: No, @JaromandaX I've used different slice method

Comment: yeah, you've used slice, which isn't the right method, and added a length argument, which effectively makes your code exactly the same as the question anyway

Comment: you need to understand the full ramifications of using splice ... your code has failed to remove one of the `5`'s because of this

Comment: What's the mistake? why it still shows one 5

Comment: the issue is, you splice the array at the current index, therefore the next element is now at the current index, however at the end of the for block, index is incremented, therefore the "new current" value is never tested therefore never removed ... one solution is to do `i--` after the splice (within the if block)

Comment: except you are not returning what the problem statement asks for - the new length

Comment: That's simple just have to use `length` now edited.. Done